# Exactly $n-1$ nonzero elements if $\det(A)=0$ for every arrangement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n^2}\in\mathbb{R}$ with the property that any $n\times n$ matrix with exactly these elements has determinant $0$. Suppose also that there are at least $n$ distinct elements.
>
> Do these conditions imply that exactly $n-1$ elements are nonzero?

This is equivalent to asking if exactly $n^2-n+1$ of the elements must be zero.

There is some reason to think so - if you have less than $n$ nonzero elements, some row has all $0$s and the determinant is $0$ for every matrix, while if you have exactly $n$ nonzero elements, then the diagonal matrix will always have nonzero determinant. However, perhaps it is possible to have zero determinant for every arrangement if we have more nonzero elements (though this appears unreasonable).

The $n$ distinct elements condition is to avoid just using the pigeonhole principle to force two rows to be the same for every arrangement.

Comment: As Rory Daulton points out, if we have at most $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ nonzero elements then we can make an upper triangular matrix which does the trick.

Comment: For $n=2$, let $x_1=-1,x_2=-1,x_3=1,x_4=1$. It seems to me that any $2 \times 2$ matrix with this four elements has zero determinant and no one is zero.

Comment: @Holonomia sweet!

Comment: Well, that's settled for $n=2$, but I haven't been able to make any progress on even $n=3$.

Comment: I have posted a new question asking about just the $n=3$ case: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322100/3-times-3-matrix-always-has-determinant-0-must-7-of-the-elements-be-0

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Holonomia has given a counterexample for $n=2$ in a comment, but the problem statement seems to be true when $n\ge3$. For the moment I can only come up with the following proof. I hope someone can do better.

**Assumptions and notations.**

- $n$ is always $\ge3$.
- $X$ always denotes *the* $X$ in question. It is always assumed that $X$ has at least $n$ distinct entries and every rearrangement of the entries of $X$ produces a singular matrix.
- $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n)$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $e=\sum_{i=1}^ne_i=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$.
- $S_n$ is the symmetric group of order $n$.
- For any $v=(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)^T\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\sigma\in S_n$, let $v^\sigma=(v_{\sigma(1)},v_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(n)})^T$ be the vector obtained by permuting the entries of $v$ according to the permutation $\sigma$.

To prove the problem statement, we need four lemmas. The proof of the first one is the most laborious. The other three are easy.

**Lemma 1.** Let $n\ge3,\,m\ge2$ and $Y=\pmatrix{y_1&y_2&\cdots&y_m}\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ be any matrix such that $y_{11}>y_{12}>\cdots>y_{1m}$. Then the entries below the first row of $Y$ can be rearranged in a way such that

- at least $m-1$ columns of $Y$ are neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$, or
- some $m-2$ columns of $Y$ are neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$, one of the remaining columns is parallel to $e$ and the other is orthogonal to $e$.

*Proof.* We shall prove this statement by mathematical induction on the number of columns $m$. In the base case $m=2$, if both columns of $Y$ are parallel (resp. orthogonal) to $e$, interchange $y_{i1}$ and $y_{i2}$ for every $i>1$. Then neither of the new $y_1$ and $y_2$ is parallel (resp. orthogonal) to $e$. Also, as $n\ge3$, at most one of the two new columns is orthogonal (resp. parallel) to $e$. Hence the base case is true.

In the inductive step, suppose $m>2$. We first permute the entries below the first row of $Y$ such that the entries of $\operatorname{vec}(Y[2:n,\,1:m])$ are arranged in descending order. It follows that $e^Ty_1>e^Ty_2>\cdots>e^Ty_m$ and $y_1\ge y_2\ge\cdots\ge y_m$.

If $y_1$ is neither parallel to nor orthogonal to $e$, we may remove it from $Y$. The dimension of the problem is then reduced by $1$ and the result follows from recursion/mathematical induction.

Now suppose $y_1$ is parallel to $e$. Let $y_1=ae$. There are three possibilities:

1. All entries in the submatrix $Y[2:n,\,2:m]$ are equal to $a$. Since $a=y_{11}>y_{12}>\cdots>y_{1m}$, none of the last $m-1$ columns of $Y$ is parallel to $e$. As $e^Ty_2>\cdots>e^Ty_m$, at most one of $\{y_2,\ldots,y_m\}$ is orthogonal to $e$. Hence the result follows.
2. $Y[2:n,\,2:m]$ has exactly one entry whose value is some $b\ne a$. Since $y_1\ge y_2\ge\cdots\ge y_m$, it is necessarily true that $a>b=y_{nm}$ and
   $$
   Y=\left[\begin{array}{c|cccc}
   a&y_{12}&\cdots&y_{1,m-1}&y_{1m}\\
   \hline
   a&a&\cdots&a&a\\
   \vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots\\
   a&a&\cdots&a&a\\
   a&a&\cdots&a&b\\
   \end{array}\right]
   $$
   If $b\ne(1-n)a$, interchange the bottom entries of $y_1$ and $y_m$. The new $y_1$ is then neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$. If $b=(1-n)a$ instead, swap the bottom entries of $y_2$ and $y_m$. The new $y_2$ is then neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$. In either case the dimension of the problem is reduced by $1$.
3. $Y[2:n,\,2:m]$ has two entries whose values $b$ and $c$ are not equal to $a$. Again, as $y_1\ge y_2\ge\cdots\ge y_m$, both $b$ and $c$ are smaller than $a$. Therefore, at least one of $(n-1)a+b$ and $(n-2)a+b+c$ is nonzero. So, by exchanging either the bottom entry of $y_1$ for $b$ or the two bottom entries of $y_1$ for $b$ and $c$, the new $y_1$ is neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$ and the dimension of the problem is reduced by $1$.

Next, suppose $y_1$ is orthogonal but not parallel to $e$ (hence $y_1\ne0$). There are four possibilities:

1. There exists some $y_{ij}\in Y[2:n,\,2:m]$ that differs from the values of both $y_{11}$ and $y_{k1}$ for some $k>1$. If we exchange $y_{k1}$ for $y_{ij}$, the new $y_1$ is neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$.
2. All entries in $Y[2:n,\,2:m]$ are equal to $y_{11}$. As $0=e^Ty_1>e^Ty_2>\cdots>e^Ty_m$, none of $y_2,y_3,\ldots,y_m$ is orthogonal to $e$. Also, as $y_{12}>\cdots>y_{1m}$, at most one of $y_2,y_3,\ldots,y_m$ is parallel to $e$. Hence the result follows.
3. Every entry in $Y[2:n,\,2:m]$ is equal to some entry below the first row of $y_1$. Since the entries of $\operatorname{vec}(Y[2:n,\,1:m])$ are arranged in descending order, this case implies that all entries of $Y[2:n,\,2:m]$ are equal to $y_{n1}$. By the same argument in case 2, we see that none of $y_2,y_3,\ldots,y_m$ is orthogonal to $e$ and at most one of $y_2,y_3,\ldots,y_m$ is parallel to $e$.
4. Every entry in $Y[2:n,\,2:m]$ is equal to some entry on $y_1$; some is/are equal to $y_{11}$ and some is/are unequal to $y_{11}$. Since the entries of $\operatorname{vec}(Y[2:n,\,1:m])$ are arranged in descending order, we must have $\operatorname{vec}(Y[2:n,\,1:m])=(y_{n1},\ldots,y_{n1},y_{11},\ldots,y_{11})^T$ and $y_{21}\ge y_{n1}>y_{11}=y_{nm}$. So, if we exchange $y_{n1}$ for $y_{nm}$, the new $y_1$ is neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$ and the dimension of the problem is reduced by $1$.$\ \blacksquare$

---

**Lemma 2.** If $v\in\mathbb R^n$ is neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$, then $\{v^\sigma:\sigma\in S_n\}$ spans $\mathbb R^n$.

*Proof.* Since $v$ is not parallel to $e$, there exists some $v_i$ such that $nv_i\ne e^Tv$. Without loss of generality, assume $v_1$ is such an entry. Since
$$
w=\pmatrix{(n-1)v_1\\ e^Tv-v_1\\ e^Tv-v_1\\ \vdots\\ e^Tv-v_1\\ e^Tv-v_1}
=\pmatrix{v_1\\ v_2\\ v_3\\ \vdots\\ v_{n-1}\\ v_n}
+\pmatrix{v_1\\ v_3\\ v_4\\ \vdots\\ v_n\\ v_2}
+\cdots+
\pmatrix{v_1\\ v_n\\ v_2\\ \vdots\\ v_{n-2}\\ v_{n-1}}
$$
lies inside $\operatorname{span}\{v^\sigma:\sigma\in S_n\}$, so are all columns of $W=(nv_1-e^Tv)I+(e^Tv-v_1)ee^T$. The spectrum of $W$ consists of a simple eigenvalue $(n-1)e^Tv$ and also an eigenvalue $nv_1-e^Tv$ of multiplicity $n-1$. Since both of them are nonzero, the result follows.$\ \blacksquare$

---

**Lemma 3.** Denote the columns of the $X$ in question by $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$. Suppose that for some $k<n$, the vectors $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$ are neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$. Then $\{x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n\}$ is linearly dependent.

*Proof.* Suppose the contrary. Then we can extend $\{x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n\}$ to a full basis $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k,x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$. By lemma 2, for each $j\le k$, there exists a set of permutations $P_j\subseteq S_n$ and a set of coefficients $\{c_j^{\sigma_j}:\sigma_j\in S_n\}\subset\mathbb R$ such that $u_j=\sum_{\sigma_j\in P_j}c_j^{\sigma_j}x_j^{\sigma_j}$. It follows from the multi-linearity of the determinant function that
$$
0\ne\det(u_1,\ldots,u_k,x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n)
=\sum_{\sigma_1\in P_1}\cdots\sum_{\sigma_k\in P_k}
c_1^{\sigma_1}\cdots c_k^{\sigma_k}
\det(x_1^{\sigma_1},\ldots,x_k^{\sigma_k},x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n)
=0.
$$
Thus we arrive at a contradiction.$\ \blacksquare$

---

**Lemma 4.** Suppose $w=(w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n)^T\in\mathbb R^n$ is a vector that (a) contains at least two nonzero entries and (b) is neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$. Then it has a nonzero entry $w_i$ such that, by setting $w_i$ to zero, the resulting vector (i.e. $w-w_ie_i$) is still neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$.

*Proof.* Let $w_1,\cdots,w_r\ne0$ for some $r\ge2$ and $w_i=0$ for all $i>r$. If $e^Tw-w_i=0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,r$, we must have $w_1=w_2=\cdots=w_r$. But then $e^Tw-w_1=(r-1)w_1\ne0$. Hence $e^Tw-w_i\ne0$ for some $i\le r$, i.e. $w-w_ie_i$ is not orthogonal to $e$. Since $w-w_ie_i$ still has one nonzero entry and its $i$-th entry is zero, it is not parallel to $e$.$\ \blacksquare$

---

We are now ready to prove the problem statement.

**THE MAIN PROOF.** Move $n$ distinct entries to the first row of $X$ and apply lemma 1 to $Y=X$ with $m=n$. Then perform an extra permutation of the columns of $X$ if necessary, so that one of the following cases holds:

1. $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ are neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$.
2. $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-2}$ are neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$, $x_{n-1}\perp e$ and $x_n\parallel e$.

By lemma 3, $x_n$ is zero in case $1$ and either $x_{n-1}$ or $x_n$ is zero in case 2. By swapping $x_{n-1}$ with $x_n$ if necessary, we may assume that $x_n=0$ in both cases. The two cases thus merge into one:

- $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-2}$ are neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$; also, $x_{n-1}\ne0=x_n$.

Now suppose some $x_j$ has at least two nonzero entries. We pick two entries of $X$ and swap them as follows:

- If $j=n-1$, pick any $x_{ij}\ne0$ and swap it with $x_{in}\,(=0)$.
- If $j<n-1$, then by lemma 4, we can pick a nonzero $x_{ij}$ from column $j$ such that $x_j-x_{ij}e_i$ is neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$. We can also pick an index $k$ such that $\{e_k,x_{n-1}\}$ is linearly independent. Swap $x_{ij}$ with the zero entry $x_{kn}$.

Then the last two columns of $X$ become linearly independent and the first $n-2$ columns remain neither parallel nor orthogonal to $e$, but this is impossible, by lemma 3. Therefore each column of $X$ has at most one nonzero entry, i.e. $X$ has at most $n-1$ nonzero entries. Now the result follows, because $X$ is also supposed to have $n$ distinct entries.